Colab: not enough RAM to load Llama 3
I was following a tutorial in Youtube, when wanted to load Llama3 8B:
model_name = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=hugging_face_key)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=hugging_face_key)

Got:
Your session has failed because all available RAM has been used

Tried: model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=hugging_face_key, low_cpu_mem_usage=True)
But again the same error

Try switching to Kaggle kernels.

@JohnnyCheesecutter how?

Given that it’s an 8-billion-parameter model, requiring approximately 16GB of space, free Colab notebooks lack the capacity to load it.

High-RAM env is not available for me  (Colab Free Plan)

I edited my answer, here is a medium article which I found : https://medium.com/@rohanvermaAI/llama-3-what-we-know-and-how-to-use-it-in-free-collab-24ec5d6058ff
